# Issue in Deploying java war ( rest apis written with jaxrs ) in Wildfly 9.0

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, jboss, wildfly

I deployed a war file in tomcat and the rest api's are working well.

But when i deploy the same war file in Wildfly 9.0 i am getting the errors. Error details attached in the screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see only debug or info lines in your logs

Comment: yep. When i am running the same project from netbean IDE application is running and serving rest api's properly. But when i am deploying war file in standalone Wildfly 9.0 server i am getting above logs and application is not serving rest-api's

Comment: Please update your question with error log. Log you have posted doesn't have any error.

Comment: Is your war in "deployed" state? You can check it via the admin console or the `wildfly-9/standalone/deployments` folder. This folder contains your deployables and for each of them a file with the same name and a suffix (.undeployed / .deployed / .failed).

Comment: I checked in deployments folder and it's in deployed state.

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration is needed for JAX-RS according to the documentation.

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Reference: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/JAX-RS+Reference+Guide